# Activate Dev account for Office 365

Tags: office365

I have tried to sign up for a Office 365 dev account on this page: http://dev.office.com/devprogram 
After receiving a confirmation e-mail, I click on a link provided in the mail in order to finish my sign up.
But each time I click on the link I get routed to a URL that says:

*Sorry, we can’t finish signing you up 
The service you’re subscribing to isn’t available for one of the following reasons:
• It’s no longer offered by Microsoft.
• You’ve already tried this service. You can sign up for a trial only once.
• The beta or trial you’re requesting has expired.
• The promotion code has already been used.*

I have never requested a trail, so I don't know what is wrong here. I hope someone has experienced this issue and can help me solve it.

Best Regards 
Christoph

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Microsoft supporting, not a programming problem.

Comment: Hmm... ok, thought I could find someone who had the same problem. But if you don't accept this kind of question then that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different email.  It'll work then.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I would like to keep everything under one account. I will close this question and contact Microsoft for support. Thanks for your help.

Comment: totally frustrated me too, that's why I went the 'new email' route.